# where would I define this helper in Ember for handling site search functionality

Tags: ember.js

I am just starting out with Ember and am curious if I had a template like the following:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <input type='text' id='myVal' /><button {{action "searchInventory"}} class='search_inventory'>search inventory</button>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Where would I define the searchInventory helper? It seems like it might be in some global controller that might forward it to a search results route; I have an InventoryItemController but how can I hook up the searchInventory action to this? What would be the Ember way to set this up?

Can I tell ember when invoking the action to use that controller like:

```
{{action "searchInventory" controller:"InventoryItem" }}
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you have structured your app, but assuming you have a controller for the template above, you should define the action on that controller within an 'actions' hash. Also, you should use the

```
{{input}}
```

handlebars helper instead of using the input tag. If you do that, you can have a property on the controller for this template, say 'searchTerm' for which you can provide a valueBinding, like this:

```
{{input type="text" valueBinding="controller.searchTerm"}}
```

This will bind the input the user types into the input element to the searchTerm property on the controller. Hope this helps.